# Как сместить один из графиков вправо в matplotlib? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

я начал работать с matplotlib и столкнулся с такой проблемой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выводе двух графиков, числа одного накладываются на другой. Подскажите, как этого избежать?

Вот часть кода, которая это визуализирует:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex='row')
ax1.plot(range(len(loss)), loss, label='loss')
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_xlabel('Epoch number')
ax1.set_ylabel('Minimal loss')

ax2.plot(range(len(acc)), acc, label='acc', color='r')
ax2.set_xlabel('Epoch number')
ax2.set_ylabel('Accuracy')
ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Попробуйте перед `plt.show()` добавить строку с  `fig.tight_layout()` .

Comment: Просто увеличьте размер графика с помощью figsize